# total derivative of function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose one has a function:

$G(x,y) = H(x,y) + L(x,y)$

Is it possible to evaluate the **total** derivative of $G$ with respect to $H$?  That is, is it possible to compute,

$\frac{d G}{d H}$

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$G(x,y)=H(x,y)+L(x,y)$$
$$\begin{cases}
dH=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}dy \\
dL=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}dy \\
dG=dH+dL=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\right)dx+\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right)dy
\end{cases}$$

$$\frac{dG}{dH}=\frac{dH+dL}{dH}=1+\frac{dL}{dH}$$
$$\frac{dG}{dH}=1+\frac{\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}dy}{\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}dy}$$

$$\frac{dG}{dH}=1+\frac{\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx} }{\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}}$$
Do not say that it is the derivative of $G$ relatively to $H$ which should be a non-sens.

Loosely speaking, it means that if $y$ changes to $y+dy$ and $x$ changes to $x+dx$ , then the resulting infinitesimal changes of $G$ and $H$ are in the proportion $\frac{dG}{dH}$.

The above formula shows that this quotient cannot be expressed in terms of $H$ only. Obviously, $L$ in also involved (more exactly the partial derivatives of $L$).

Moreover it isn't sufficient : $\frac{dG}{dH}$ also depends on the path considered on the curve $y=y(x)$ . One cannot analytically express $\frac{dG}{dH}$ if the function $y(x)$ isn't defined in order to compute $f'(x)$ which appears in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

No.  $G$ is not a function of $H$, so it doesn't make sense to talk about the derivative of $G$ with respect to $H$ in any sense.  $G$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.